Perform event when out of Gridview
I have a program which I am updating, and what I am going to do is that when I click outside of a GridView type object, it will send an instruction only once to other objects (Textbox, Labels, etc). I did some tests on the MouseLeave() event and it does in a certain way what I need, but it does it all the time while I am outside the GridView and that is my detail that when I am outside the GridView, the event repeats every so often without What can stop it, any ideas or other events I can use?
Private Sub GridView2_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView2.MouseLeave
    ComboBox55.Text = "A"
    ComboBox44.Text = "B"
    ComboBox13.Text = "NO"
    NumericUpDown14.Value = 0
    ToggleSwitch34.IsOn = False
End Sub


What control is this? You say GridView, which seems to suggest that this is a Web Forms app, but your code also suggests that you are using ComboBox and NumericUpDown controls, which suggests that this is a WinForms app. How about you apply the appropriate tag(s) so that we don't have to guess? If it is WinForms and it's a GridView rather than a DataGridView then it must be a third-party control, so you need to explain that as well.

You say that you want to do something "when I click outside" but the MouseLeave event has nothing to do with clicking. It occurs when the mouse pointer leaves the bounds of the control, so it's clearly not relevant to you. If you really did care about clicking then it would be Click/MouseClick events of other controls that were relevant, but I doubt that's the case either. I suspect that what you really care about is when this grid control loses focus, which could happen by mouse click or it could happen other ways. Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the actual problem.

OT, it's VERY bad that you have controls with the names you do. That suggest that you have large numbers of controls that are distinguished by nothing but a number that has no descriptive meaning. You should pretty much ALWAYS use a descriptive name for EVERYTHING, so anyone reading your code - that includes you later, when you've forgotten what those numbers actually represent - can see exactly what each control and everything else actually represents and is used for.

I suggest you attach events to the controls inside of the GridView, and thus you eliminate the challenge of trying to process some click that occurs outside of the GridView.  And what about keyboard tabbing out of the GV? Seems easy to suggest code to run outside of the GridView, and only one time. What is the REAL goal and purpose here? Your real goal is not outlined here, and as a result, my spider sense suggests that you want something to occur as a result of some change in the GV - that being the case, attach events to controls in the GV, and not some click outside of GV.

@AlbertD.Kallal, thank you, In the GV there are two events, the click and double-click, the first when you click sends information from another GV to be called to show information and what the double-click does is enable controls for editing information. The goal is that when the user exits editing mode, the controls return to their default values. I had thought about the part about when the mouse is outside the GV but it repeats itself non-stop for the same reason.

Is this a web form, or a windows form? For a windows form, then you obviosity have more options. If winforms, then create a boolean var at the form level, and set it = false, when your code runs, you set it = true, and thus the code will not run again. Of course when going back into the GridView, then you set that flag = false. This can thus control your code to run only one time.

@jmcilhinney, thank you, That's right, GridView is a third-party control, DevExpress to be exact, is a Winform application. And yes, what you mention is correct, it is not necessarily when the click occurs outside the GridView, but when the user exits the editing mode that is configured in the Double click event.

@AlbertD.Kallal, yes, is a Winform, so it is not necessary to execute a GV event? Only with the boolean value?

No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Please edit your question and provide ALL the relevant information.  I have updated the tags already.

@jmcilhinney, Thank you for your advice, I'll do it.

Perhaps you want the LostFocus event of the GridView? https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView._events
